# How to place the icon in the same place regardless of the screen size using css?

Tags: css

i want to place the svg in same place on screen irrespective of screen size. I want the svg to be placed in the same div meaning to the extreme right of text "Please try again". Also with code below the svg occurs to the right of text Debug and is aligned okay on big screens however on small screens it appears on the url. How can i solve this could someone help me with this. Thanks.

Below is the code,

```
<div className="wrapper">
    <div className="message">
        <svg className="message_close error"></svg>
        <div>
            <div> Please try again 
                <div >Server </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                 <div>
                     <h2>Debug</h2>
                     URL: {request.responseURL}
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 450px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.message {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: white;
color: $topcon_blue;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
position: relative;

.message_close{
    position: absolute;
    left:calc(100% - 80px);

    &.error{
        top: 105px;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working code sample please? You can do so in the Stackoverflow editor itself or via jsFiddle. Makes it easier for us to help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

Change the .message_close and .error css like this. I tested it.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.message {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: $topcon_blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}

.message_close {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.message_close.error {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="message">
      <svg class="message_close error"></svg>
      <div>
        <div> Please try again
          <div>Server </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h2>Debug</h2>
            URL: {request.responseURL}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```